# How can I get rid of indentation after an equation?

Tags: equations, indentation

I'm a total newbie to LaTeX and I get very annoyed about this. Every time I write an equation, the text following the equation has some indentation but I don't want it to be there!

```
Look at the following formula

\begin{equation}
K_BT_k=Dexp\left\lbrace -\frac{1}{2N(E_F)|J|}\right\rbrace
\end{equation}

where $Dexp$ is a ...
```

The line starting with "where ..." is indented and looks horrible. Some people told me about `\noindent` but do I really have to write this command after every single equation?

Comment: This question just popped up for some reason and I did a double take to see who asked it.  It's amazing that Juan literally started out with LaTeX here three years ago and has got so much reputation since then.

Comment: Thanks @RyanReich :) Although for full disclaimer, I was actually [pretending to be a novice user](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/179/under-construction-seeding-is-going-on) when I wrote this question. I was very involved with the site at the beginning, from area51 and through the early beta.

Comment: I knew something was wrong!  You are apparently a good actor as well :P

Answer (score 103, accepted):

Remove the blank lines, either by actually removing them or adding '%'s:

```
Look at the following formula
%
\begin{equation}
K_BT_k=Dexp\left\lbrace -\frac{1}{2N(E_F)|J|}\right\rbrace
\end{equation}
%
where $Dexp$ is a long sentence guaranteed to take us over the
end of this line and well into the next.
```

Simple, but subtle!

**Explanation:** (added in edit)

The indentation is created by the fact that, as far as TeX is concerned, the word 'where' begins a new paragraph and you've decided that new paragraphs should be indented (or rather, you haven't decided that new paragraphs shouldn't be indented).  TeX detects this by the presence of the blank line (well, actually by the double newline, but what it considers a double newline is a little complicated so "blank line" is best for now).  So to tell TeX that there isn't a new paragraph there, I simply remove the blank line.  As I like to keep my source code with lots of visual spaces between things, I do this by putting the comment marker '%' on the blank line.  Deleting it (as in Caramdir's answer) would be equivalent as far as TeX is concerned.  In fact (as Caramdir pointed out in his answer), both the blank line before and after should be removed.  As originally written, there are *three* paragraphs where there should (according to the wording) be just one.  Although the fact that the equation starts a new paragraph is less obvious, it still can have an effect.

Note that although it may have almost the same effect, using the `\noindent` command here would be wrong.  Using `\noindent` says "This is a new paragraph, but I don't want it indented." whereas putting in the `%` says "This isn't a new paragraph.".

Comment: Could you explain why?? I'm a total newbie!!

Comment: The space you have after the \end{equation} signals a new paragraph (that's what empty lines mean.) Commenting out the empty line (with a `%` means that effectively there is no empty line, but visually you still get the separation that you seem to want in the source between the equation environment and the rest of the text.

Comment: @Juan A. Navarro: Caramdir suggests removing the line _before_ as well.  I agree (well, I'd put in the comment character) as it's all syntactically the same paragraph; I was concentrating on the afterwards and missed the before.

Comment: Explanation for removing the empty line above the equation: spacing. Try compiling 
  `Look at

  \begin{equation}
  a
  \end{equation}`

with and without an empty line.

Comment: This answer has helped with a similar situation when using `\foreignblockquote` of the package `csquotes`.

Comment: @ischeriad: Great!

Answer (score 28):

Just remove the empty lines before and after the equation.

Comment: Andrew was faster.

Comment: But you got the "before" as well so +1.

Comment: +1 I just hate using comments for anything more than commenting.

Comment: @mbq: do you mean in (La)TeX files or on this site?

Comment: why? why should I remove those empty lines? could you elaborate? I insist because this answer is getting a lot of votes, but I don't think it answers the question see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172/how-newbie-friendly-should-the-site-be

Comment: @Andrew (La)TeX (and program codes)

Comment: @Juan I'll try; in (La)Tex not all whitespaces are ignored; one or more empty lines form "begin new paragraph" command. So you can just not write it, as in this solution, or comment out this command writing % in the empty line as in Andrew's solution. (Which IMO is a bad practice, still just works.)

Comment: @mbq: With most languages, I'd agree with you.  I hope, though, that you'd agree that the decision on how much to spread out ones code is largely a matter of personal taste.  I find that grouping and separating things helps me understand my own source code and that blank lines are visually the easiest way for me to do this.  However, since blank lines have special meaning in LaTeX, the equivalent in LaTeX of a blank line in, say, a perl script **is** a line beginning with a %.  So, for me, a line with just a percent character on it is not a comment line.

Comment: @Juan: Andrew answer (which btw you should accept) already has a nice explanation. An I added a comment about the before to his. I'm aware you are impersonating a LaTeX beginner, but if somebody cannot figure it out from Andrew's answer and its comments, they should go back to Word...

Comment: @mbq: There are some situations where using a % to avoid a newline is a must to avoid too additional whitespace. E.g. when you begin a paragraph with a `\label{}` there should not be any space between the closing } and the next word. Putting a % after the label lets you begin the paragraph on a new line without TeX seeing a superfluous newline character.

Answer (score 4):

For comparision, in ConTeXt, the relation between  blank lines in input and indentation in output can be controlled using the `indentnext` key. For example, if you set

```
\setupformula[indentnext=no]
```

then, there is no indent after an equation (irrespective of whether the input has blank lines or not). Similarly, if you set

```
\setupformula[indentnext=yes]
```

then th next line is always indented. To get the default LaTeX-like behavior (indent if the input has blank line), usé

```
\setupformula[indentnext=auto]
```

The same logic works for other environments like descriptions, itemize, enumerate, etc.

Answer (score 3):

I always put a

```
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
```

in the preamble of the document (i.e. before `\begin{document}`). Of course, then all indentations are supressed and if you want something to be indented, you have to do this manually.

Comment: Using the [`parskip` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/parskip) (rather than setting the lengths `\parskip` and/or `\parindent` separately) is sometimes preferred.