# How Can I Avoid Writing "\noindent" After Equations

Tags: math-mode, equations, indentation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get rid of indentation after an equation?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565/how-can-i-get-rid-of-indentation-after-an-equation)

Just a quick question:

For clarity, in my LaTeX files I always leave a blank line after equations:

```
$$ equation $$

<- empty line ->

Text continued.
```

This automaticaly indents the next line. I know I can use the `\noindent` command to correct this, but it is rather tedious after every equation. Is there some universal command for this?

These are the packages I use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
```

Comment: Not direct related your question but you shouldn't use `$$` ... `$$` with LaTeX but `\[` ... `\]` instead. See ["Why is \[ … \] preferable to `$$`?"](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/2975) for an explanation.

Comment: What are the advantages of \\[  \\]?

Comment: See my updated comment above. The `\ ` in `\[` `\]` were removed by the wiki syntax :-(

Comment: @milcak: Please indent code lines by 4 spaces, and not with `>`. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "101010" on it). Thanks & welcome to tex.sx.

Comment: I agree with the duplicate.  milcak: can you take a look at the question and answers that lockstep linked to?  They may answer your question.  If so, we'll close this one as a duplicate to make it easier for others searching this site.  If not, please edit your question to explain why not.  Thanks!

Comment: @Martin: [That link](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503/2975) you provided has the huge drawback that the accepted answer doesn't say anything about the "why" ...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yet another version:

```
If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are such that 
\[
    a^2 + b^2 = c^2,
\]
then, does it follow that ...
```

Comment: This is my favorite convention.  Then the equation "looks" displayed.

Answer (score 6):

with empty lines you get wrong vertical spacing. Uses always something like

```
If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are such that 
%
\[  a^2 + b^2 = c^2, \] 
%
then, does it follow that there is triangle whose sides' length is $a$, $b$ and
$c$?
```

And also `$$` should be used only for TeX and not LaTeX.

Answer (score 2):

How about using the following scheme, which makes the input clearer:

```
If $a$, $b$ and $c$ are such that \[
  a^2 + b^2 = c^2, 
\] then, does it follow that there is triangle whose sides' length is $a$, $b$ and
$c$?
```

Comment: Yes thank you that is better. But I would still prefer something that would keep the code for the entire equation in one line.

Comment: @milcak: If you want to add an (almost) empty code line after your equations you can just place a single `%` in it, which avoids that it is taken as the start of a new paragraph.

Comment: @milcak: You still get the equation in one line. The `\[` `\]` is markup, not equation.

Answer (score 2):

In ConTeXt, like almost all top level environments, `\setupformulas` and `\defineformula` accept a `indentnext` option that control the indentation of the next paragraph.

With `\setupformulas[indentnext=no]`

```
\startformula 
  ...
\stopformula

This is not indented
```

LaTeX's default behavior is equivalent to `indentnext=auto`.
See [ConTeXt wiki](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Indentation#Setting_up_indentation_after_an_environment) for more details.