# \noindent won't work for stopping indentation after a math formula

Tags: equations, lists, indentation, description

In this minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item [{a)}] \begin{flushleft} test1 test1 test1 test1
test2 test2 test2 test2 
\[
x^2+x+1=0
\]
%
\noindent test3 test3 test3 test3
\par\end{flushleft}
\item [{b)}] test4 test4 test4 test4
test5 test5 test5 test5
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

I don't  want the

```
test3 test3 test3 test3
```

line, after the equation indented. But neither using `\noindent` nor the trick with the "%" from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/565/how-can-i-get-rid-of-indentation-after-an-equation) question worked. Do you have any ideas how I could stop the indentation? (It is preferable, to keep everything inside the

```
\begin{description}..
```

block and not to use a different command - or if I have to use a different command, than I would like to use one that allows me to put the "a)" and "b)" at the beginning of each line and handles spacing, like the `\begin{description}` automatically.)

Comment: The indent you see derives from the fact that you're in a `description` environment, where *all* lines after the first are indented.

Comment: The alignment (or indentation) is "as expected" within a list environment like `description`. Do you want the `text3...` to be flush with the left margin of the text block, or flush left with the `description` item label?

Comment: ah, ok I see. @Werner flush left with description item label

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As egreg and Werner have hinted, the observed indentation is not caused by a paragraph, but is a feature of any but the first lines of your `description` items. You can see this by placing additional "test2" strings before the equation in your first item.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item [{a)}] \begin{flushleft} test1 test1 test1 test1
test2 test2 test2 test2 
test2 test2 test2 test2 
test2 test2 test2 test2 
test2 test2 test2 test2 
test2 test2 test2 test2 
test2 test2 test2 test2 
\[
x^2+x+1=0
\]
%
\noindent test3 test3 test3 test3
\par\end{flushleft}
\item [{b)}] test4 test4 test4 test4
test5 test5 test5 test5
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I suggest to use an `enumerate` environment instead (and to load the [`enumitem`](http://ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package to customize the environment's label).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textbf{\alph*)}]
\item test1 test1 test1 test1
test2 test2 test2 test2 
\[
x^2+x+1=0
\]
%
test3 test3 test3 test3
\item test4 test4 test4 test4
test5 test5 test5 test5
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]